# Back button android implementation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to implement an Action Bar back button in android and set similar function as the back button from android device? I can not set the parent activity in manifest, because i work on a parsing News app, I have category list, when I choose one of the categories, the NewsList appears, then when I click one News from the list, and click on the back button implemented in android manifest(parent-activity), it shows error because it doesn't know which category was chosen before.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do by adding onBackPressed() in
 @overrite
public onOptionSelected - method with

```
onOptionSelected(){switch(menuItem.getId()){case android.R.id.home:onBackPressed();break;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start NewsActivity with **startActivityForResult** from Category list.

When you press backbutton from NewsActivity then send category id/name from it with **setResult** and handle **onActivityResult** in Category list screen

More details : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: can you explain once again please? I have 3 activities:
1.category list
2.categoryClicked (loads the news list)
3.NewsActivity (displaying info about news, from this activity i want to go back to categoryClicked, and to see the category chosen in the 1st step)

Comment: If you click back press from AboutNewActivity that time Newlist activity is already in background and it has category which you chose in step1.

Comment: If you have still issue and not getting category which you choose in step1  then you can do same for three activities. Ref : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: so  what on which of the tgree activities I should put starActivityForResult, setResult and onActivityResult?